# p:fileUpload not working (file is null)

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

I cannot make the fileUpload option working. I keep having the message file is null.
Could you tell me how to fix this ?

here is my xhtml:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload mode="simple" id="recupereFile" value="#{FileUploadView.uploadedFile}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{FileUploadView.upload}" ajax="false" />
</h:form>
```

here is my java:

```
@ManagedBean(name="FileUploadView")
public class FileUploadView {

    private UploadedFile file;

    public UploadedFile getFile() {

        System.out.println(file);
        return file;

    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void upload() {

        UploadedFile file = getFile();

        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println(file);

        if(file != null) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

file is always null !

my web.xml

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
```

I have these jars:
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
commons-io_2.5.jar

Thansk for your help.

Comment: did you see this post [Upload a file step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964)

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue a few month ago here. The colleague who did this left our company, so I can't ask him. Anyway this is how the relevant parts of my web.xml look like.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also we have this context-param:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>auto</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` attribute of `p:fileUpload` should correspond to the name of the `UploadedFile` in the bean.

It should work if you replace `FileUploadView.uploadedFile` with `FileUploadView.file` in the `p:fileUpload`:

```
<p:fileUpload mode="simple" id="recupereFile" value="#{FileUploadView.file}" />
```

Comment: Hi , thanks you're probably right about this. However, it doesn"t work, even when I change that.